# How to remove a label before input in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck now I want to remove a label before input in a form.
that label was append from another function and I want to delete it back by using jquery method. but if I used **insertAfter** to add and used on **next()** and **remove()** it work as well but I want to add that label before input and if i used before to remove it will remove input instead of labels.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Default balance : 1000</label>
   <input name="amount" class="form-control" id="amount" placeholder="" style="" value="0" type="text">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#amount").parent().prev("label").remove();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `parent()`:

```
$("#amount").prev("label").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `label` is the previous sibling of the input element `#amount`, so call `prev()` on the `input` element, not on its parent

```
$("#amount").prev("label").remove();
```

Comment: my god I confusing now

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call `parent()`, to get the sibling through `prev()`

```
$("#amount").prev("label").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$("#amount").prev("label").remove();
```

or

```
$("#amount").parent().find("label").remove(); // if not direct previous element
```